# After updating my Entity Framework, I get an error "Schema specified is not valid"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework

Receiving Error when I updated my entityframework edmx.
I'm using Entity Framework database-first with ASP.NET MVC [VB.NET], everything was going fine until I updated the entity this time, I got an error out of no where, I already spent couple hours trying to solve it.

I have to also mention that we use a [development , staging and production] servers to host our database.

Error:

> Schema specified is not valid.
> Database.ProjDW.ssdl(2,72) : error 0169: All SSDL artifacts must target the same provider. The ProviderManifestToken '2012' is different from '2008' that was encountered earlier.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid.
>
> Errors:
> Database.ProjDW.ssdl(2,72) : error 0169: All SSDL artifacts must target the same provider. The ProviderManifestToken '2012' is different from '2008' that was encountered earlier.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several hours of searching here and there I found the issue and I'm posting it in case anyone faces it will not suffer like me.

**Error was because of:** I have two different server's hosting my databases and they have different SQL Server versions.

**Solution:** exclude your `.edmx` file and open it in Notepad, then edit `ProviderManifestToken` to the correct year - so for me it was 2012, I changed it to 2008 and now it's working fine again :)